# Remove from normal flow and set relative position to itself

Tags: css

```
<div id="foo">
    <div></div>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

How do you get top of "bar" to be positioned -5px relative to its original position and also removed from the normal flow?

### Attempt 1

```
#bar {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Doesn't work since "bar" is not removed from normal flow

### Attempt 2

```
#foo {
    position: relative;
}
#bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Doesn't work since top of "bar" is placed -5px relative to "foo"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
#bar {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -5px;
}
```

See this live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mRTJK/)

Comment: So simple. I don't know why I didn't think about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might need to do something link this:

```
#foo {
    position: relative;
}
#bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: That won't work - the #bar element will have its position set relative to its parent, not its original location.

Comment: jacktheripper is right. I meant to say this in Attempt 2. I fixed it.